# Mouse moves, but cannot click

Tags: macos, mouse, daemons

My mouse just got stuck: I could still move the pointer, but clicks would not register. This occurred with both my external Magic Trackpad, and the laptop's internal trackpad, apropos of nothing. As such, I assume it to be a software thing, rather than hardware.

Rebooting the machine did not work. However, it did all of a sudden start working when it came up from sleep (as I carried it to our service desk). The keyboard remained operational throughout, giving me enough input to be able to do basic things.

As I say, I assume this to be a software thing: a service/daemon malfunctioning. If so, is there a command I can issue at the terminal to restart said service (if that would even work, given rebooting didn't)? If not, any other ideas, if it happens again?

(High Sierra 10.13.6; 15" MBP Mid-2014)

Comment: Maybe try downloading karabiner it to see if the computer is receiving input?